# Как присвоить кортежу переменных значения, которые вводит пользователь

Tags: python

я представляю это как то так, но так не работает. Я понимаю, что можно присвоить каждую переменную отдельно и будет работать. Вопрос именно в том, можно ли присваивать кортежу значения из пользовательского ввода и как это делать. Заранее Спасибо !!

```py
print("Эта программа, может считать за вас. Введите начало, конец и интервал между целыми числами")
(a,b,c) = int(input())
for i in range(a,b,c):
    print(i, end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы это работало нужно (без обработки неверно введенных данных):

```py
a, b, c = [int(x) for x in input("Эта программа, может считать за вас. Введите начало, "
                                 "конец и интервал между целыми числами: ").split()]

for i in range(a, b, c):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

`input()` возвращает строку.
Чтобы положить значения в целочисленные переменные, вам придётся порезать эту строку и привести каждое строковое число к целочисленному типу.

Например:

```
(a, b, c) = map(int, input().split())
```

Если вы хотите вводить числа построчно, каждое на своей строке, придётся запустить `input()` столько раз, сколько чисел нужно ввести.

Например:

```
a, b, c = (int(input()) for _ in range(3))
```